# php generating rssfeed filename from field in a table?

Tags: php, rss, filenames

SOLUTION

```
<?php
    include("authenticate.php");
    $user = $_SESSION['UserName'];
    $initialdata = $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ccregisterfeed WHERE username = '$user'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($initialdata)){
    $filename = $row["feedlink"];
    // var_dump ($filename);
    } 
    $initdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($initialdata);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ccshowcontent JOIN ccaudio ON ccshowcontent.id = ccaudio.id WHERE ccshowcontent.username = '$user' ORDER BY ccshowcontent.id DESC")
    or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $items[] = $row;
    }

$rss = createXML($items,$initdata);
//echo "feed updated!";
$filename = ($filename);
file_put_contents($filename,$rss);
header("Location: ccupload.php?message=".urlencode("Show saved and feed updated"));
?>
```

FULL SCRIPT

```
<?php
  include("authenticate.php");
  $user = $_SESSION['UserName'];
  $initialdata = $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ccregisterfeed WHERE username = '$user'");
  $initdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($initialdata);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ccshowcontent JOIN ccaudio ON ccshowcontent.id = ccaudio.id WHERE ccshowcontent.username = '$user' ORDER BY ccshowcontent.id DESC")
or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $items[] = $row;
}

function createXML($items,$data){

    $xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rss version='2.0' xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
<channel>
<atom:link href='".$data['feedlink']."'
rel='self' type='application/rss+xml' />
<title>".$data['feedtitle']."</title>
<link>".$data['websitelink']."</link>
<category domain=''>".$data['category']."</category>
<copyright>".$data['copyright']."</copyright>
<pubDate>".date("D, d M Y H:i:s O", strtotime($data['pubdate']))."</pubDate>
<language>en-us</language>
<description>".$data['feeddescription']."</description>
<image>
<title>".$data['feedtitle']."</title>
<link>".$data['websitelink']."</link>
<url>".$data['imagelink']."</url>
<description>".$data['imagetitle']."</description>
</image>";

$audiodir = "http://thetradingcardgenerator.com/MP3/";
foreach($items as $key => $item){
    $path = $audiodir.$item['path'];
    $pdate = strtotime($item['pubdate']);
    $date = date("D, d M Y H:i:s O", $pdate);
    $xml .="
<item>
<title>".$item['title']."</title>
<link>".$path."</link>
<guid>".$path."</guid>
<pubDate>".$date."</pubDate>
<description><![CDATA[".$item['description']."]]></description>
</item>";

}

$xml .="
</channel>
</rss>";

return $xml;
}

$rss = createXML($items,$initdata);
//echo "feed updated!";
$filename = '$feedlink' . ".xml";
file_put_contents($filename,$rss);
header("Location: ccupload.php?message=".urlencode("Show saved and feed updated"));
?>
```

FIRST ENTRY

I've wrote a script to generate an rss feed from data entered in a table. I want to generate the filename from a field in the table, which I created as follows :

```
$path = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$feedtitle = str_replace(" ", "", $feedtitle);
$feedtitle = str_replace("_", "", $feedtitle);
$feedtitle = str_replace("-", "", $feedtitle);
$feedtitle = strtolower($feedtitle);
$path = substr($path, 0, strrpos($path, "/"));
$feedlink = "$feedtitle" . '.xml';
```

Thus if $feedtitle was Last Nights Television the value of $feedlink would be

```
lastnightstelevision.xml
```

I've tested the script by specifying the filename and it works, data is pulled from the tables and a feed is created. This is the last part of the script :

```
$rss = createXML($items,$initdata);
$filename = 'myfeed.xml';
file_put_contents($filename,$rss);
header("Location: uploadcontent.php?message=".urlencode("Show saved and feed updated"));
?>
```

Which creates a feed name myfeed.xml on my server.

However I want the filename of the feed to be the value of $feedlink. I know this is probably something basic but I can't figure out how to do it.

I tried :

```
$filename = ".$feedlink";
$filename = ".$feedlink[feedlink]";
```

And many other combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get that filename from RSS, try this

```
$attribute = $rss->channel->children("atom", true)->link->attributes();
$filename = $attribute["href"];
```

Or this, if you want to get it from results returned from your first query

```
$filename = $initdata['feedlink'];
```

The result above is a whole path, so if you need only the filename from that path, use this

```
$feedlink = "http://mywbsite/mydir/lastnightstelevision.xml";
$filename = basename($feedlink);
```

Output:

```
lastnightstelevision.xml
```

[Working demo](http://ideone.com/Gx8NmQ)

Comment: No I'm trying to get it from a field. I've already generated the filename and stored it in a field. If $feedlink has a value of "lastnightstelevision.xml" how do I use that as the filename?

Comment: @MBM What's the name of that fild and which method you're using to fetch records; `mysql_fetch_object()`, `mysql_fetch_array()` or ... Share that part of PHP code.

Comment: I've posted the script. The field with the link is named feedlink. I don't need to ammend the value of feedlink, I want to use it's exact value.

Comment: It should be $filename = $row["feedlink"]; I've updated the code to show the revised query. var_dump ($filename) is giving the correct value and it's working! Thank you!!!! The code should be useful to anyone that wants to generate rss feeds.